# How to create a button which is always directly below an image when the image's frame changes size

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I'm currently using this sample code to produce an ImageView with a button below it, which produces a log when pressed.

```
- (void)loadView {
[super loadView];

imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SteveJobsMacbookAir.JPG"]];
[imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(80.0, 20.0, 160.0, 230.0)];
[imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];

[[self view] addSubview:imageView];

UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(cropImage) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(124.0, 258.0, 72.0, 37.0)];
[button setTitle:@"Crop!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[[self view] addSubview:button];
}
```

When I press the "Crop!" button, the above image's size changes size:

```
- (void)cropImage {
[imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(80.0, 20.0, 160.0, 230.0)];
}
```

However, the button stays in the same place, instead of being below the image. How can I resize the image's frame, whilst having the button move to be once again directly below it?

Comment: As a proper programmer Please use and follow **Autolayout** to achieve like above. set button and image view vertical distance and below it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply give y position of your button to a variable with respect to the y position of your imageView.
Try this

```
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(124.0, imageView.frame.size.height + imageView.frame.origin.y + 20, 72.0, 37.0)];
```

+20 is provided for some space between your imageView and button. 
Hope this helps :)

Comment: Perfect! For anyone reading this in the future, you simply use this line of code every time the above image is resized, and the button's position relative to it is updated. Thanks a lot, Deepesh! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Following Code

```
- (void)loadView {
[super loadView];

imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SteveJobsMacbookAir.JPG"]];
[imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(80.0, 20.0, 160.0, 230.0)];
[imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];

[[self view] addSubview:imageView];

UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
//Change bellow line
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(cropImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(124.0, 258.0, 72.0, 37.0)];
[button setTitle:@"Crop!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[[self view] addSubview:button];
}  
//Change to this function
- (void)cropImage:(UIButton *)sender {
[imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(80.0, 20.0, 160.0, 230.0)];
sender.center = CGPointMake(sender.center.x,imageView.center.y);
}
```